# Не обновляется список в GUI Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

**Что должно происходить:** Есть первый список с выбором предметов при действии <'Button-1'> создается второй список (проблемный) с выбором того, какое действие произвести.

**Проблема:** Не обновляется отображение Listbox'a в GUI при изменении переменной.

**Что пробовал:**

1. Сначала это был один список, который я пытался перезаписать и отобразить (безуспешно)
2. Пытался те же действия запихать в функцию, которая вызывается, после нажатия на первый список (безуспешно)
3. Пытался добавить, что-то типа `list.update()`, `frame.update()` (безуспешно)
4. Пихал код с сменой Listbox'a в циклы (безуспешно)

```py
########## СПИСОК ПРАВОГО МЕНЮ ##########

sr_listA = ['Сложение', 'Вычетание', 'Умножение', 'Деление', 'Корень']
sr_listB = ['sin', 'cos', 'tang', 'cotang']

right_listA = Listbox(right_frame, width = 33, height = 120)
right_listB = Listbox(right_frame, width = 33, height = 120)

if operations == 0:
    for ind in range(0, len(sr_listA)):
        x = str(sr_listA[ind])
        right_listA.insert(ind, x)

elif operations == 1:
    for ind in range(0, len(sr_listB)):
        x = str(sr_listB[ind])
        right_listB.insert(ind, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

И так. Решил сам. Дело было вот в чем:

```py
    operations =  left_list.curselection()
```

operations получал в свое значение кортежи. А я пытался их считать, как int. 
Ну и после каждой смены списка добавил еще window.update()